# go use fsnotify watch file ischanged not working

Tags: go

I use the library (http://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify) to monitor the file system.

I m trying to adjust the repository example to match my requirements, but when i do so the program is not working anymore.

I commented the done channel within the ExampleNewWatcher function

```
done := make(chan bool)
<-done
```

As a result, now when i run the example, this channel does not output anything anymore.

```
event, ok := <-watcher.Events
```

Complete code：

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func ExampleNewWatcher() {
    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer watcher.Close()

    done := make(chan bool) // if i commen this line the `panic` not norking
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case event, ok := <-watcher.Events:
                if !ok {
                    return
                }
                log.Println("event:", event)
                if event.Op&fsnotify.Write == fsnotify.Write {
                    log.Println("modified file:", event.Name)
                }
                panic("just for test") // new output this line

            case err, ok := <-watcher.Errors:
                if !ok {
                    return
                }
                log.Println("error:", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    err = watcher.Add("/tmp/foo")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
   <-done // comment this
}

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
func main() {
    // create the test file
    var err error
    file, err := os.Create("/tmp/foo")
    check(err)

    _, err = file.Write([]byte("hello world"))
    check(err)

    stopchan := make(chan struct{})

    // test change file
    go func() {

        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            file1, err := os.OpenFile("/tmp/foo", os.O_RDWR, 0644)
            check(err)
            d := strconv.Itoa(i) + "hello world"
            _, err = file1.Write([]byte(d))
            check(err)
            err = file1.Close()
            check(err)
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second) // wait the context  writed to the file
        }

    }()

    ExampleNewWatcher() // monitor file

    stopchan <- struct{}{}
}
```

Comment: When you comment the done channel, it lets the function ExempleNewWatcher finish, thus the call to watcher.Close that was deferred is called. Thus the watcher is closed, thus no events.

Comment: @mh-cbon that right answer. thks

Comment: @mh-cbon can I post you comment as answer?